# I want to add the settings for numberOfMonths etc to the datepicker, but I dont't know how to do it

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to add the settings for `numberOfMonths`, `showWeek` and `firstDay` to the `datepicker`, but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried inside `function()`, inside `datepicker`, but nothing works.

```
numberOfMonths: 3,
showWeek: true,
firstDay: 1

<script>  
 $(function() {

 $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val()
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pLA8C/

Comment: What is the `.val()` for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the correct syntax;

```
<script>  
$(function() {

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1
    });

});
</script>
```